# Keyboard shortcurts for Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, keyboard-shortcuts

I just do this in android emulator for copying and pasting the data in edittext.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> = Copy
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> = Paste

But it didn't works. So, i need to know if these shortcuts are working or not in emulator. Or, any other special shortcuts available for android emulator. Anyone knows this means, help me to find out the problem? Hope this will very useful for me. I'm working on Windows 7 Professional OS.

Comment: @LukasKnuth : Why it's not work for me. How did you use? Did you give any special permisstions.

Comment: Nope. Worked out of the box for me. I'm on Linux btw.

Comment: @LukasKnuth : I'm on Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate working fine for me :)

Comment: @LukasKnuth : Do you know that Shortcuts in Windows 7 professional OS.

Comment: @xjaphx : Did you add any special method when the AVD Creation?

Comment: I don't think they're different...

Comment: @LukasKnuth : Okay, i'll try.

Comment: It just works on default, I don't have to alter anything.

Comment: @xjaphx : Then why it's not working for me. Okay. I'll try to find out the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

For more information: [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping).

Comment: Copying and pasting a text-filled image is inaccessible to webcrawlers and screen readers.  And yes, there are software developers who use screen readers.

Comment: For an updated list, in the emulator -> settings -> help

Comment: Is there a shortcut for switching between the Android Studio code files and the Android Studio emulator now that it is possible to run the emulator in the same application window? *Android Studio > Preferences > Tools > Emulator > Launch in a tool window*

Comment: I've created a custom shortcut in Android Studio preferences to toggle the embedded emulator: `ctrl + shift + E`.

Answer (score 42):

You can see the shortcuts by clicking on the "more" button:

[image: emulator window]

And going to the "Help" tab:

[image: extended controls window]

Answer (score 9):

You can check current config from console

```
emulator -help-keys

  When running the emulator, use the following keypresses:

    Ctrl-H          Home button
    Ctrl-M          Menu (Soft-Left) button
    Ctrl-Backspace  Back button
    Ctrl-Escape     Power button
    Ctrl-Equal      Volume up button
    Ctrl-Minus      Volume down button

  note that NumLock must be deactivated for keypad keys to work
```

Comment: Getting `unknown option: -help-keys`

Comment: Looks like it was removed from the `emulator` cli.

Answer (score 6):

Copy the text you want:

Ctrl + C = Copy

Then when the emulator is in focus, paste using:

Ctrl + V = Paste

Then in the edit text that you want, long click on the field until you see the emulator paste button pop up above your cursor. Click that and it should work.

Comment: Ctrl+V is not needed as it won't work.

Answer (score 6):

In the Android Studio Emulator the ctrl+v doensn't works, just hold the left mouse button for a second and paste menu will appear (in textbox etc.).

Answer (score 5):

For Mac OS, the most important shortcuts are:

`Cmd + Backspace`: Back button

`Cmd + O`: Overview (The square button)

`Cmd + Shift + H`: Home (The center button)

You can see the rest from the Triple Dot menu, go to Help section.